# Why is xcode giving me these building warnings and errors?

Tags: xcode, build, warnings

I created an app that plays a sound when you press a button and it was working fine initially. I'm not sure what happened, I deleted one of the files and now xcode keeps giving me a warning in reference to a file Not being found. I've deleted and recreated the file, commented out the code using the file, and cleared but build but nothing seems to be working. I'm new to xcode and app development. Here's the errors I keep getting:

Check dependencies

```
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/adrienneiverson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeakUp1-aoakahingahxuwfhopwfckqlxewc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeakUp1.app/Bye.mp3

Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/adrienneiverson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeakUp1-aoakahingahxuwfhopwfckqlxewc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeakUp1.app/Bye.mp3

CpResource ../../Sounds/Mp3/Bye.mp3 /Users/adrienneiverson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeakUp1-aoakahingahxuwfhopwfckqlxewc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeakUp1.app/Bye.mp3
    cd "/Users/adrienneiverson/Desktop/SURE PROGRAM 2011 - GA TECH/SpeakUp1"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -resolve-src-symlinks "/Users/adrienneiverson/Desktop/SURE PROGRAM 2011 - GA TECH/SpeakUp1/../../Sounds/Mp3/Bye.mp3" /Users/adrienneiverson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeakUp1-aoakahingahxuwfhopwfckqlxewc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SpeakUp1.app

error: /Users/adrienneiverson/Desktop/SURE PROGRAM 2011 - GA TECH/SpeakUp1/../../Sounds/Mp3/Bye.mp3: No such file or directory

error: /Users/adrienneiverson/Desktop/SURE PROGRAM 2011 - GA TECH/SpeakUp1/../../Sounds/Mp3/Bye.mp3: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what multiple build commands they're talking about and the file is located in the directory that they're saying its not in...I'm lost....

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the build folder?

Or is that what you meant by `I've deleted and recreated the file, commented out the code using the file, and cleared but build but nothing seems to be working.`?

Tjeu